# API gateway blocking requests with content in body

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to post a request through AWS API gateway with postman.
I have aws IAM on and it appears to be working. I can send a request with nothing in the body I get a 200 response back from my lambda function.

I would like to send a binary file in the body however whenever I add anything, form-data, raw or binary data to the body of the request I get this message:

```
{
    "message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'POST\ ..."
}
```

I have tried adding
image/png and application/octect-stream to `Binary Media Types`
and also tried specifying a model with just one field in it and that doesn't work either.

Any help would be much appreciated. I tried posting on AWS forums but there is no "post", "ask a question" or "create" button to actually ask a question, so back to old trusty stackoverflow.

Cheers. Mitch.

Edit API gateway setup:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: AlarmEndpoints
  version: '2019-03-02T03:22:39Z'
servers:
- url: https://602wer34n1.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/{basePath}
  variables:
    basePath:
      default: /dev
paths:
  /alarm/message:
    post:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 200 response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Empty'
      security:
      - sigv4: [
          ]
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: arn:aws:apigateway:ap-southeast-2:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:962000000000:function:alarm_message/invocations
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: '200'
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        httpMethod: POST
        contentHandling: CONVERT_TO_TEXT
        type: aws
components:
  schemas:
    Empty:
      title: Empty Schema
      type: object
  securitySchemes:
    sigv4:
      type: apiKey
      name: Authorization
      in: header
      x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: awsSigv4
x-amazon-apigateway-policy:
  Version: '2012-10-17'
  Statement:
  - Effect: Allow
    Principal:
      AWS: arn:aws:iam::962000000000:user/alarm_user
    Action: execute-api:Invoke
    Resource: arn:aws:execute-api:ap-southeast-2:962000000000:*/*/*
```

Lambda Function:

```
import json
import os
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    var = os.environ.get("a_variable")

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps({'message': 'Hello from Lambda 2!',
                            'echo': event,
                            'data': var})
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share your code? I have a couple of answers showing how to upload binary data through API Gateway but yours seems like a different case

Comment: Sorry it took me 2 nights to work out how to export the aws API. I was originally developing in the web page.

Comment: Can you also share your handler?

Comment: Done! Not much to it but that's it

Comment: I'd rule API Gateway and your code out. Your problems seems to be on the V4 Signed Request. Check this link for reference, it may ring a bell: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-troubleshooting.html

Comment: Nothing really, will move away from using postman to drive the api. I just tried adding raw data to the packet and that gets sent through. Thanks for the effort

Comment: I am sorry I can't help :( Good luck!